# MySQL table for following structure

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I want to create a MySQL table according to the picture and data flow below. What would be the best structure for the table?

[image]

Comment: It looks like a candidate for nested sets.

Answer (score 0):

The data is not sufficient. There are too many assumptions involved.
The best possible way would be to Create these tables with columns
Table Column
Kitchen KitchenId KitchenType
KitchenDuration KitchenId KitchenDuration
KitchenWork KitchenId KitchenCount CleaningCount

Answer (score 0):

You can create three tables.

1. List item
2. Duration
3. item type

Duration table schema can be

```
create table Duration(Id int(11) primary key auto_increment,Duration varchar(50));
```

Like  4 month,6 Month and 12 Month

```
create table item_type(Id int(11) primary key auto_increment,type varchar(50));
```

Like Home,commercial

```
create table item(Id int(11) primary key auto_increment,name varchar(50),typeId int(11),durationId int(11));
```